# Reference request for philosophies like Stoicism

Tags: reference-request, stoicism

I'm doing a bit of a review of philosophical systems... At one end being the logic and reason of Critical thinking, in the middle are logical problems with "accepted" answers, and at the other end "philosophies" that may be accepted as true but are hard to logically prove. These would probably be considered ethics or morality - ways to live one's life.

Going back to Ma'at you have the things you aren't supposed to do or the things you are supposed to do that are often called virtues. There would be the Maxims of Delphi. It seems to me though that Stoic philosophy such as described by Zeno of Citium, Marcus Aurelius, etc. is rather an unusual example... which probably is just a reflection of my limited knowledge.

Could you perhaps suggest any other analogous philosophical systems?

Comment: Pyrhonists would be a start.  I would also argue Nicomachean Ethics only because of the emphasis on moderation.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: Jules Vuillemin has argued that there are just 4 *types* of systems and two more attitudes, perhaps you could look in his book *What are Philosophical Systems?* Cambridge UP 1986

Comment: Ahhh yes. After some sleep, I figured out that Nicomachean Ethics would fit in there... I had been looking at that before, but you know how it is. You look at something, circle around and come back with a different understanding... Pyrrhonism, philosophy of Skepticism derived from Pyrrho of Elis (c. 370–c. 272 bce), generally regarded as the founder of ancient Skepticism. I'll have to examine that. Thank you, "Swami". I'll have to examine that. In that I'm looking for a certain type of belief, it may fit. I'm looking for "Dharmic" systems, part of which shows up in Samuri beliefs of all places

Comment: Maybe in the Platonic era Eleatic Monism (a la the Parmenides), Hedonism (in the Epicurean sense), Cynicism (in the Diogenes of Synope sense, not the later Academic one), Ephemeralism (as in Heraclitus) and at the non-ancient or non-Greek end Taoism, Manicheanism (as in Gnosticism), 'Care' (in the Feminist Ethics sense) or Compassionism (as in 'the Perennial Philosophy' or Buddhism).  Not picking abstruse examples on purpose, just trying to and make them as different as possible.  All of these distinctly split from narrow logic on purpose, if you are looking for contrasts to Criticism.

Comment: Thank you @jobermark. I'll have to review them at the very least to be able to list and categorize them. I'm diving into Stoic philosophy right now, but only after writing a comment about how common knowledge of the value of philosophy to daily life seems to have been lost during the war between science and religion that raged in the early 20th century(ie. Scopes trial).